# docker-compose: Permission denied ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the ASP.NET Core 2.2 project

Tags: docker, docker-compose, external, connectivity, asp.net-core-2.2

I have tried to build and to run on MS Windows 10 Pro a Linux docker image/container by using docker-compose and

https://github.com/JasonGT/NorthwindTraders/blob/master/docker-compose.yml
https://github.com/JasonGT/NorthwindTraders/blob/master/Northwind.WebUI/Dockerfile

from

https://github.com/JasonGT/NorthwindTraders :

```
 >docker-compose up
```

It failed:

```
...
Creating northwindtraders-master_data.sql_1 ... done
Creating northwindtraders-master_northwind_1 ... error

ERROR: for northwindtraders-master_northwind_1  Cannot start service northwind: driver failed programming 
 external connectivity on endpoint northwindtraders-master_northwind_1   (9db694c218ad8d10dee00d597624e3ede6dd1312ab70ea5e664f6dd8c9ca7764): 
 Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:80: unexpected error Permission denied

ERROR: for northwind  Cannot start service northwind: driver failed programming external connectivity 
 on endpoint northwindtraders-master_northwind_1 (9db694c218ad8d10dee00d597624e3ede6dd1312ab70ea5e664f6dd8c9ca7764): 
  Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:80: unexpected error 
  Permission denied ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

When running:

```
>docker-compose ps
```

It results in the following output:

```
               Name                            Command              State             Ports
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
northwindtraders-master_data.sql_1    /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr      Up         0.0.0.0:5433->1433/tcp
northwindtraders-master_northwind_1   dotnet Northwind.WebUI.dll   Exit 128
```

How should I edit

https://github.com/JasonGT/NorthwindTraders/blob/master/docker-compose.yml
https://github.com/JasonGT/NorthwindTraders/blob/master/Northwind.WebUI/Dockerfile

or differently run docker-compose by using additional options to fix the issue?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue than you.

Solved that by creating a user on Win10 for docker to run. Then I had to share the project folder with the docker user (full control). It made the trick.

Make sure docker is using this user account (check that on docker > settings)